# BrowserWindow.Launch NOT decode string

Tags: encoding, decode, coded-ui-tests

In a codedui, this line decodes the link before opening the browser:

```
myBrowser = BrowserWindow.Launch(New System.Uri("http://blablabla/main.aspx?sn=JFA%3d%3d"))
```

I want it to remain encoded in the url. In other words, when the browser opens, the %3d are already converted to "=" in the string.

```
http://mylinkhere/main.aspx?sn=JFA==
```

I want them to remain as %3d.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this bro, this is in **c#** btw.

```
String URL = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("sn=JFA%3d%3d");
window = BrowserWindow.Launch(new Uri("http://blablabla/main.aspx?" + URL));
```

Comment: It's not working as planned... The url is getting encoded twice and it shows that way in the browser.

Comment: Nevermind, I decoded it and then encoded it and now it works. Thanks!